# How do I store parsed HTML into a database and compare values within the database

Tags: c#, html, mysql, parsing, compare

My database has fields like:
ID(nvarchar), Start Date(date), End Date(date), Status(bit)

I am currently parsing HTML from a website in order to compare the 2 values(1 from my local db, other from website) to determine if they are the same. If they are the same values - perfect. However if the dates or status are different by over 7 days or Status shows Inactive instead of Active(or vice versa) I want it to 'Add to Final Report' where after it goes through all values stores a report.txt file on the desktop(not sure still)

```
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.LenovoWarrantyConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        ArrayList lenovolist = new ArrayList();
        SqlCommand myCommand = conn.CreateCommand();
        myCommand.CommandText = ("SELECT SerialNumber from Warranty");
        SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
        int count = myReader.FieldCount;

        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                //Loop through Serial Numbers
                string result = myReader.GetValue(i).ToString();
                //Iterate through Lenovo's Serial Checker 1 by 1
                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("serialCode").Focus();
                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("serialCode").InnerText = result;
                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("warrantySubmit").InvokeMember("Click");
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                MessageBox.Show("Script Completed");
                //Get System Summary Info
                foreach (HtmlElement el in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div"))
                    if (el.GetAttribute("className") == "fluid-row firstfluid")
                    {
                        var record = el.InnerText;
                        lenovolist.Add(record);
                        //MessageBox.Show(record, "System Summary");
                    }
                //Get Base Warranty, Warranty Upgrade, and Priority Support
                foreach (HtmlElement el in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div"))
                    if (el.GetAttribute("className") == "fluid-row Borderfluid")
                    {
                        var record1 = el.InnerText;
                        lenovolist.Add(record1);
                        MessageBox.Show(record1, "Base Warranty, Warranty Upgrade, Priority Support");
                    }
            }
        }
        foreach (var items in lenovolist)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(items.ToString());
        }
```

I have about 300~ rows in the database.

At first I thought about storing the parsed HTML within an arraylist in order to compare to the database however - **I need to now store the parsed info into the db (unless dates / status is different)**

thanks in advanced for any help in this

Comment: It's not clear where exactly you're stuck.  Ideally you would build a class which represents one "object" of the data (the handful of values).  That class would contain the logic for comparing them.  Construct an instance of the class from what you have in the database, construct another instance from what you have in the HTML, and compare the two instances of the class.  It seems like you might be over-complicating this.

Comment: Could you show me an example of the logic to compare them? I am not too sure how and I cant seem to find a solid resource

Comment: Well, you already describe some of that logic: `"if the dates or status are different by over 7 days or Status shows Inactive instead of Active"`  Are you asking how to compare two `DateTime` values to see if they're more than 7 days apart?  How to compare two string values to see if they're different?  It's not really clear what the problem is, honestly.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining it but yes to both of them. I do not know how to approach it. for example the date in my database is DD/MM/YYYY where the HTML string I parse is YYYY/MM/DD. The problem with this is that I dont know how to break my parsed string apart? How do I separate my parsed string and compare it to its respective database counterpart? ---- In the string there are 6 key dates but I do not know how to compare them to the 6 dates I have in my database

Comment: You don't "break it apart".  You convert both values to `DateTime` objects and compare those objects.  You can use operators like `>` and `<` and `==` to compare values.

Comment: I see alright so if my string is Start Date: 2015-09-09 End Date: 2017-09-09 -- How do I convert it when there are more than just numbers. I know how to convert "2015-09-09" to a DateTime but I need to automate this and not input the dates manually - The program has to automatically convert to datetime and compare -- I may be overthinking all of this and I appreciate your patience with me  !

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165448.aspx

Comment: Alright I will look into it more, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a confusion related to how to deal with data here:

1) Data belongs to the data layer (MySql server in your case) and should almost always store data only, not presentation related information

2) Html code belongs to presentation layer (fed to the browser to display the information)

Ok, enough theory. In your case:

1) Define a table for data fetched from the web. E.g.

**WebData**

```
ProductId INT
TheDate DATE
SerialCode VARCHAR(128)
```

2) Parse Html file and transform the data before inserting to WebData table. Date can be parser using [DateTime.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx), [DateTime.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx) or the exact counterparts - [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) or [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22(v=vs.110).aspx) (I recommend the last one).

3) You can issue a select that look like this ([DateDiff](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) is used to check that time span)

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(W.TheDate, P.EndDate) > 7 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS IsActive, <other info here>
FROM Product P
   INNER JOIN WebData W ON W.ProductId = P.ProductId
```

Of course, this can be transformed into an update to maintain `Status`.

Comment: 1) I am an idiot, idk why I didnt think of that - I get stuck and I start overthinking things. 2) My dates from the web come out YYYY/MM/DD can DateTime.TryParseExact convert that automatically to DD/MM/YYYY?.  3) That last line is an innerjoin right?

Comment: 2) TryParse/Exact converts virtually any string representation to a DateTime. It is strongly recommended to store date-time as DateTime in the database to easily allow computations, ordering etc. DD/MM/YYYY is just a way of displaying a date (presentation). Yes, INNER JOIN (I will fix it, as I am used to T-SQL where INNER is implied).

Comment: So the program I am creating loops through around 300~ serials - so everytime it loops I should be converting the html strings I parse into strings + datetimes and store those values into a seperate table in my database - after all the loops are completed is when I should do the compare between the 2 tables. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, parse html strings, store the data in a table and then you can compare the tables (if the logic tends to be more complex than described, it can be done in a stored procedure).

Comment: Thanks - I am relatively new to working with databases, I appreciate all the help! The logic is pretty much - Compare Serial Number if(serialnumbers match){compare dates + compare status} -- At the end if there are any dates / status' that return differently I need to add it to a report that the program will alert the user every week. (The program will automatically run at 5am everyday and give a report at x time of day once a week as an update) -- I still need to do that step after I finish comparing